# "Tables" package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use "tables" package in R in order to put a pretty table in tex.

Here is my original data frame (let's call it "sample").

```
   type year High-Low coeff.star  sd.star
1   Emp    2      Low     0.0099 (0.0098)
2   Emp    2     High      0.006 (0.0098)
7   Ind    2      Low  0.0357*** (0.0088)
8   Ind    2     High  0.0309*** (0.0087)
3   Emp    5      Low     0.0128 (0.0209)
4   Emp    5     High     0.0031 (0.0208)
9   Ind    5      Low  0.0869*** (0.0198)
10  Ind    5     High  0.0743*** (0.0196)
```

My initial intention is to convert this data frame into a table like this

```
           Emp                  Ind
       Low     High   |      Low     High
2year 0.0099  0.006   |  0.0357*** 0.0309***
     (0.0098)(0.0098) |  (0.0088) (0.0087)
--------------------------------------------
5year 0.0128  0.0031  |  0.0869*** 0.0743***
     (0.0209)(0.0208) |  (0.0198) (0.0196)
```

However, I am struggling with how to use this tables package proficiently and I find it very difficult to implement this. If it's hard to do.. I want to borrow you guy's wisdom to display a table like this...

```
           Emp                  Ind
       Low     High         Low     High
2year 0.0099  0.006     0.0357*** 0.0309***
5year 0.0128  0.0031    0.0869*** 0.0743***
```

Comment: tabular is more of a summary table, an alternative to proc template.  It might be better to put your data frame into a matrix exactly how you want it and use something like `Hmisc::latex` to automate the latex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I got pretty close but it was pretty messy. I did have to use `rehape2`. Here's what I got. First, the input data

```
library(tables)
library(reshape2)

dd <-data.frame(
    type="c("Emp", "Emp", "Ind", "Ind", "Emp", "Emp", "Ind", "Ind"),
    year = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
    High.Low = c("Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High"),
    coeff.star= c("0.0099", "0.006", "0.0357***", "0.0309***", 
        "0.0128", "0.0031", "0.0869***", "0.0743***"),
    sd.star = c("(0.0098)", "(0.0098)", "(0.0088)", "(0.0087)", 
        "(0.0209)", "(0.0208)", "(0.0198)", "(0.0196)")
)

#reshape and check types
mm<-melt(dd, c("type", "year", "High.Low"), 
    measure.vars=c("coeff.star", "sd.star"))
mm$year<-factor(mm$year)
mm$High.Low<-factor(mm$High.Low, levels=c("Low","High"))
```

Here I had to melt the data a bit so that  the "star" columns head had their own row. Next I used tabular

```
tabular(year*Heading()*variable ~  
    Heading()*type*Heading()*High.Low*value*Heading()*identity, mm)
```

And that gave this result

```
                 Emp               Ind                
                 Low      High     Low       High     
 year            value    value    value     value    
 2    coeff.star 0.0099   0.006    0.0357*** 0.0309***
      sd.star    (0.0098) (0.0098) (0.0088)  (0.0087) 
 5    coeff.star 0.0128   0.0031   0.0869*** 0.0743***
      sd.star    (0.0209) (0.0208) (0.0198)  (0.0196)
```

Hopefully that gets you pretty close.

Comment: You are amazing! Wow... I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hehe. That was a tough one too.

Comment: BondedDust. I didnt know the system.. anyway i did! Many thanks.. to MrFlick